# On differential polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Definition:** A differential polynomial is a polynomial with indeterminates $y$, $y'$, $y''$, $\ldots$ with coefficients in $K[x]$, algebra of polynomials with coefficients in a field $K$.

An example of a differential polynomial is
$$(1+x)y^2y'+(y'')^2(y''')^5-x^4 yy'y''y'''y^{(4)}-2x. $$
Such polynomials are studied in "Differential Algebraic Geometry" and solution of this polynomials are called "Differential Varieties".

**My question:** Is it possible to express a differential polynomial as an infinite series with terms of linear differential equations?

For example, is it possible to have an equality of the form
$$(y')^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(x)y^{(n)}? $$
Of course, we need a norm to speak about convergence.

Note that the Taylor series of $(y')^2 $ does not satisfies the condition.

Comment: In other words, you are asking whether there is an isomorphism of $K-$algebras $K[x,y,y',y'',\dots] \cong K[x][[y,y',y'',\dots]] / (y,y',y''\cdots)^2$
 preserving the generators, right? I really do not think so, but I wouldn't be able to prove it on the spot. Why do you believe this is the case?

Comment: By the way, in your first example, I believe that the differential polynomial is either the RHS or the LHS, but not the equation itself

Comment: @57Jimmy Actually I don't believe that this is the case. But if it was true, then I would be unstuck in my research on differential varieties.

Comment: I see :) well, I am sorry that I cannot help you further, but the topic seems to be very interesting!

Comment: @57Jimmy Thanks, I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an algebra $[E,F]=I, [J,E]=E, [J,F]=-F$, $I$ is central. I would like to have a differential polynomial realization of it, but such that it is not degenerate when $I$ acts as $0$. For example the dif. polynomial $E=i\sqrt{a} x$, $F=i\sqrt{a} \partial_x$, $I=a$, $J=x\partial_x$ where $a$ is a number, is a realization, but $E=F=0$ when $a=0$. Is there another one such that neither $E$ nor $F$ is $0$ when $a=0$ ?

Comment: @A.Babichenko Actually, I do not understand what you mean. Please explain your question in details.